# Atualizar dataTable no primefaces

Tags: primefaces, datatable

Como posso atualizar minha `dataTable` sem precisar reiniciar a aplicação? Da maneira que estou fazendo a tabela é atualizada após um <kbd>F5</kbd>, porém se eu dou <kbd>F5</kbd> novamente, ela fica desatualizada novamente.

Por exemplo: tenho 3 cargos, minha `query` traz apenas o cargo `x`. Dai quando eu edito um cargo `x` para `y` ele continua aparecendo na tabela, se eu dou um <kbd>F5</kbd> ele some, porém se eu dou <kbd>F5</kbd> novamente ele retorna.

Eu estou tentando atualizar a tabela da seguinte forma:

```
<f:event listener="#{controleAuditoriaLibBean.carregarPesquisa}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
```

E o meu método que carrega a pesquisa:

```
public void carregarPesquisa(){
        try{
            //Traz apenas se for "Liberação" e "Aguardando"
            SolicitacoesDAO solicitacaoDAO = new SolicitacoesDAO();
            list = solicitacaoDAO.listarPorUsuario("Liberacao", "Aguardando");

        }catch(RuntimeException ex){
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao tentar listar as Auditorias");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Em que momento que tu precisa atualizar o datatable?

Comment: quando abria a página, já consegui resolver agora só falta descobrir como eu atualizo componentes de uma tela em uma outra tela. Por exemplo, quero atualizar o form da tela x quando clico em salvar na tela y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido, coloquei `@PostConstruct` no meu método que faz a pesquisa no banco

Comment: Sim, pois resolvi o problema, então reaproveitei a pergunta para tirar uma duvida.